# I have set segue but says has no segue with identifier

Tags: ios, segue

I have made a demo to log weibo.after I get token jump to other page.

```
- (void)sinaweiboDidLogIn:(SinaWeibo *)sinaweibo
{
    [self saveWeiboInfo];

    NSLog(@"uid= %@ accessToken= %@", sinaweibo.userID, sinaweibo.accessToken);

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];

}
```

then turn error after get token:

```
2013-02-18 17:31:50.683 WeiboTimeline[5690:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<WeiboLoginViewController: 0x712a850>) has no segue with identifier 'login''
```

the identifier set right.

but in viewdidLoad ,it can jump right.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDictionary *dic = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"weiboUserData"];
    NSString *token = [dic valueForKey:@"access_token"];
    NSLog(@"token= %@", token);
    if (token != nil) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
    }
}
```

after the code run,when token get the save ,and next time app open can jump right.

why?they are the same code,thanks for you teach.